# Inserting a record with an auto increment according to the results

Tags: mysql

I am developing a comment database for an application and I have the following problem which I don´t know how to solve.

Basically I got a table like this:

```
comment_id | comment_text | thread_id | internal_id
-----------------------------------------------------
1              text1           1            1
2              text2           2            1
3              text3           1            2
```

Basically, what I want is that if I do an insert with a **thread_id = 1**, the **internal_id** should be automatically **3**.

Is there any way to do this by using an INSERT query ? As I don't want to use a PHP script to get the last internal_id and then insert this number incremented.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a try, assuming that `comment_id` is set as `auto_increment`.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (comment_text, thread_id, internal_id)
SELECT  'your comment' AS comment_text,
        1 AS thread_id,
        COALESCE(MAX(internal_id) + 1, 1) AS internal_id
FROM    tableName
WHERE   thread_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use several solutions:

1. You can try to use triggers for calculating internal_id inside a specific scope of  thread_id.
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html
2. Create additional table with structure: **thread_id, last_internal_id**. Read from this table, put value to a specific comment and increment last_internal_id.

Also you should take into account that it doesn't matter what approach you will use you can get the same values for internal_id if two people adds 2 comments at the same time. So for avoiding it you should use locks or transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If your engine is MyISAM, you can have `internal_id` be AUTO_INCREMENT as part of a tuple `(thread_id, internal_id)`.

Check this out:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

Comment: My engine is MyISAM fortunately. How can I apply those changes ? as a default value ? I'm a bit confused

Comment: Something like CREATE TABLE comments (comment_id INTEGER NOT NULL, comment_text TEXT, thread_id INTEGER NOT NULL, internal_id INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (thread_id, internal_id)). And then when you insert, don't specify a value for internal_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (internal_id,comment_text,thread_id ) (
SELECT MAX(internal_id)+1,'TEXT',1 FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE thread_id =1 AND (
SELECT MAX(internal_id) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE thread_id =1));
```

I have not the database to test it, so I might be wrong. Correct me if I made a mistake.